# How to use code migration toolkit in magento2?

Tags: module, code, code-migration

Below is the Github link for Code migration toolkit magento2.
https://github.com/magento/code-migration

I need to migrate my magento1 modules to magento2 standards. Does this supports it? If it supports please anyone suggest how to start using this tool?

inside < src > what files do we need to put? the full code fodler? or only the local directory? I have 5 custom modules of m1 what are the files to be included in < src > directory?

Comment: The modules are not migrated as such using this tool. It basically make the architect based on the M1 module and some changes in code base on the architect. You will have to code the things yourself. So it do approx 20-25% of the job.

Comment: Yes, Thank you, I need to start using this tool, seen some links and it is mentioned to maintain directories like <src> <dest> and so on.. in <src>  m1 modules to be put i read. Do i need to put all files inside local directory of m1? or what?

Comment: Better to follow the instructions, you will get the module ready to start working on.

Comment: Where is the instructions please?

Comment: https://github.com/magento/code-migration

Comment: From the above link 
Prerequisite Directories
where all these directories to be created ? If you migrated please can you explain it step by step?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80217/discussion-between-jafar-and-law).

Comment: The link is not working. Any other solutions for code migration?